# Why modulus operator does not work on that code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 12;
    int i, res;
    string digits = to_string(n);


    for(i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++){
        res = 0;
        res = n % digits[i];

    if (res != 0){
        res = false;
        break;
    }

    if (res == 0){
        res = true;
    }
}
```

The digits[0] is 1, therefore: 12 % 1 = 0 = res.
However, when I run the program, res = 12, so the following if conditions do not work correctly. What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The `if` conditions are not in the loop, so they're just using `res` from the last digit.

Comment: `digits[0]` is 49, not 1.

Comment: I have changed it but is is still the same

Comment: I don´t understand why digits[0] = 49

Comment: Because when you use a `char` as a number, you get the character code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
digits[0]
```

Contains the character `'1'`, which has a numeric value of 49. You are evaluating `12 % 49` which is indeed 12.

If you want to convert a numeric character to its value, you can do it like `(digits[i] - '0')`.

Change

```
res = n % digits[i];
```

to

```
res = n % (digits[i] - '0');
```

But only if you're certain that `digits` will only contain characters that are digits.

The ASCII character codes can be found by googling for them. This page seems fine.

https://www.asciitable.xyz/

Comment: Since she created `digits` by converting a number to a string, the last condition is guaranteed.

Comment: @Barmar agreed but thought it was worth including for the next iteration of the program where they take user input.

Comment: Hopefully that input would be done to the `int` variable, not directly to the string.

Comment: @Barmar "hopefully"